# Program to find Prime numbers. Chapter 2 Self test schildt java beginner's guide

Tags: java, primes

In Self tests of chapter 2 Schildt's Java Beginners Guide there is an exercise to write a program that finds all of the prime numbers between 2 and 100.

The correct answer that the author gives is as follows:

```
class Prime {
    puЬlic static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j;
        boolean isprime;
        for(i=2; i < 100; i++) {
            isprime = true;
            for (j=2; j <= i/j; j++)
                if((i%j) == 0) isprime = false;
            if (isprime)
                System.out.println(i +" - is a prime number."); 
        }
    }
}
```

I can not understand two things

1) Condition of second FOR loop:

```
j <= i/j;
```

Is this some kind of mathematical algorithm for finding primes?

My version of the condition looks like

```
j < i;
```

2) If in the condition of the second loop put `i <= j` instead of `i < j`, then the output of the program will be empty. Why?

Thank you for help!

Explanation of second question:

When I solved this problem, relying on "my" version of the definition of a prime number, my code looked like this:

```
for(i=2; i < 100; i++) {
            isprime = true;
            for (j=2; j <= i; j++)
                if((i%j) == 0) isprime = false;
            if (isprime)
                System.out.println(i +" - is a prime number."); 
        }
```

Pay attention to the condition of the second cycle:
i <= j. Less or equal

If you rely on "my" definition of a prime number, then the equal sign in the condition should be.

Try running the program. The output will be empty.

But if the condition removes the equal sign `for (j=2; j < i; j++)`, the program will work correctly.

what is the reason?

Comment: Are you sure you put j <= i and not i <= j ? The 2nd option will terminate your loop early.

Comment: @Mwak 

yeah, i'm sure should be `j <= i;`


if i choose `i <= j`, then the 2nd loop will be infinite.
First iteration: i = 2; j = 2, loop moves on to the next iteration
2nd iteration: i = 2; j = 3, condition `i <= j` is true, loop moves on to next iteration
3rd iteration: i = 2; j = 4, condition `i <= j` is true, loop moves on to next iteration
...
...

Comment: Got it, I edited my answer to explain what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus onto these `for` loops.

```
        for(i=2; i < 100; i++) {
            isprime = true;
            for (j=2; j <= i/j; j++)
                if((i%j) == О) isprime = false;
            if (isprime)
                System.out.println(i +" - is a prime number."); 
        }
```

The first loop iterates through all numbers you want to test. Easy enough to understand, it simply tells "I want to perform the following test on all numbers from 2 to 100".

```
for (j=2; j <= i/j; j++)
    if((i%j) == О) isprime = false;
```

Now this loop is pure math.
Mathematically, a prime number :

> is a natural number greater than 1 that cannot be formed by
>   multiplying two smaller natural numbers.

(source : Wikipedia)

You therefore iterate through all numbers that, multiplied, would form i.

But do you really need to ? 
If, as an example, i = 3*25, do you need to iterate all the way to 25 to know i is not a prime number ?

The answer is obviously no, since after testing for j=3, you already know i is composite.

Mathematically, multiple algorithms exist to check whether a number is prime or composite., but a reasonably correct way to do it is to check whether a number is a multiple of [any number between 2 and its own square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division). You are performing a rounded-up version of this.

Checking for all numbers between 2 and i is redundant for reasons cited above.

EDIT : Answer to 2)

When using

```
for (j=2; j <= i; j++)
    if((i%j) == 0) isprime = false;
```

you are telling the compiler to stop looping *after* performing the test on `j==i`. Of course, when j equals i, (i%j) == 0 always evaluates to true.

In non-informatical terms, you are checking whether a number is composed of *any number, excluding 1, including itself*, whereas you should check whether it is composed of *any number, excluding 1 and itself*.

This is due to Java's way of implementing `for` loops : [they stop when the middle condition evaluates to false.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: Thank! Now it is clear. The definition of a prime number that we learned in school looks like this (literal translation):

A simple number is a natural (positive integer) number that has exactly two different natural dividers - a unit and itself.

A little different from the English version of the definition of a prime number, agree? :)

I will explain my second question with the following comment.

Comment: added an explanation to the second question in main post